# Pass ArrayList<LatLng> from ForegroundService to MainActivity

Tags: broadcastreceiver, bundle

I am fetching Latitude and Longitude coordinates and trying to send it via a broadcast to my MainActivity, however, my Bundle in the BroadcastReceiver is always null.

Here is my code so far:

ForegroundService

```
private void sendBroadcastToMapsActivity(ArrayList<LatLng> polylinePoints) {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setAction(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION, polylinePoints);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

MainActivity

```
private class DataBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("DataBroadcastReceiver: ", action);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION);
        ArrayList<LatLng> polylinepoints = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION);

        if(polylinepoints!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < polylinepoints.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("Test: ", String.valueOf(polylinepoints.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong or what I a missing?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

The error is in the onReceive method with the Bundle class.
I had to get rid of the following line.

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION);
```

So does my new method look like now

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("DataBroadcastReceiver: ", action);
        ArrayList<Parcelable> polylinePoints = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(StaticFields.STATIC_BROADCAST_ACTION);

        int size = polylinePoints.size();
```